# Ponteiro de ponteiro em C

Tags: c, array, funções, estrutura-de-dados, alocação

Fala pessoal, estou tentando entender o comportamento de ponteiro de ponteiro, mas não consigo entender. Bom, já tenho ideia de que o ponteiro aponta o endereço de memória de algo, para um outro local, assim facilitando a utilização, mas quando eu crio um ponteiro de ponteiro, tudo já fica confuso.

Segue o exemplo, a ideia é criar itens para alocar dinamicamente no Mapa, mas eu não consigo entender como o "**lista" vai agrupar diversas alocações de itens diferentes? E como eu consigo consultar o endereço de cada item?

```
typedef struct _item
{
    int conta; //contador
    char *termo; //palavra
} Item;

typedef struct _mapa
{
    int total; // número de itens no mapa
    int blocos; // número de blocos de itens alocados
    Item **lista; // vetor de ponteiros para itens
} Mapa;void
```

Eu cheguei a tentar criar uma forma de alocar um item novo, mas por não entender o comportamento do **lista, não consegui situar o local para adicionar a nova alocação. O **lista vira uma espécie de Matriz?

```
insere_termo (Mapa *mp, char *s)
{
    Item * it = malloc (sizeof(Item));
    it->termo = s;
    it->conta = 1;

    mp->lista = &it;
}
```

Comment: Se você vai colocar mais de um item `mp->lista`, você primeiro precisar alocar memória para `mp->lista`, dizendo quantos elementos, você pretende alocar, algo do tipo `mp->lista = calloc(x, sizeof(*mp->lista))`, onde x é a quantidade de elementos alocados, depois você pode inserir na lista usando a notação de array, algo do tipo: `mp->lista[i] = item`, onde `i` é o indice. E detalhe, a menos que você tenha consultado as especificações do C na ISO e esteja muito certo do que vc está fazendo, nunca comece o nome de um identicador com `_`, como em `_item` e `_mapa`.

Comment: saquei, eu teria então que alocar X vezes a lista para usar ela como um vetor, aí por ser uma alocação estática, eu consigo percorrer ela como se fosse um vetor indexado, tudo isso sem alterar as duas estruturas que eu dei como exemplo né?

Comment: Na realidade, do jeito que eu falei a alocação seria dinâmica, não estática. Se vc quiser alocação estática, teria que alterar a struct Mapa e declarar o item como `Item *lista[x]`.